# makefile から複数のmakefile を呼び出した場合の動作

Tags: makefile

環境：

- OS : CentOS 7
- make : GNU Make 3.82

トップの makefile は以下のようになっており、SUB1,SUB2,SUB3 のmakefile を呼び出すようになっていたとします。 
SUB1,SUB2,SUB3 の makefile には C ソースをコンパイルするだけの単純なものとします。

```
TARGET_LIST=SUB1 SUB2 SUB3

all:
    @for d in $(TARGET_LIST); do make -C $$d; done
```

そこで質問があります。

- (1) この状態で、SUB1 内でコンパイルエラーが発生した場合、SUB2,SUB3
  が実行されてしまいますが実行されるのが通常の動作なのでしょうか？(make -k した状態に見える）
- (2) そもそも (1) の状態になることが異常で、なにかしら makefile に記載ミスがあるのでしょうか？
- (3) makefile から makefile を呼び出した場合は、エラー発生時の停止条件はどうのような扱いとなるのでしょうか？(exit 1;？等の扱いを別途考慮し、makeifle を記載するべき？）

以上、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`make`(1) はタスクの各行のコマンドライン(=シェルスクリプト)全体の終了コードが 0 かそうでないかによって後続のタスクを実行するかどうか判断します。よって、以下のターゲット `test` は `echo done` に到達して成功します。

```
test:
    false; true
    echo done
```

`sh` で確認するならこんな感じ:

```
$ sh -c 'true'; echo $?
0
$ sh -c 'false'; echo $?
1
$ sh -c 'true; false'; echo $?
1
$ sh -c 'false; true'; echo $?
0
```

よってタスクである 1 つのシェルスクリプト中にシェルでループするとき、ループ中でのエラーで失敗させたい場合はループを中断かつ終了コードを 0 以外にしてやる必要があります。こんな感じ:

```
all:
    @for d in $(TARGET_LIST); do $(MAKE) -C $$d || exit $$?; done
```

余談ですが `Makefile` 中で `make` を起動したい場合は `make` よりは `$(MAKE)` を記述したほうがベターです。`make` で `Makefile` を駆動したときは `make` に、`/path/to/your/local/bin/make` で駆動したときは `/path/to/your/local/bin/make` に置き代わるので。

Comment: 理解できました。また、希望どおりの動作となりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

(1) ループの停止処理を書いていないので停止しないのが通常の動作となります。
ループ for を処理しているのは make ではなくシェルになります。シェルの for 文はループ内で実行されている make コマンドが成功しようがしまいがループを進めるため停止しません。

(2) 異常ではありません。

(3) シェルのfor文でループするのであれば実行結果を判定してエラーなら停止する処理を自分で記述する必要があります。

別の方法としてはシェルのフープを使わずに、以下のように make のターゲットとして記述すればSUB2のmakeコマンドが失敗した時点で停止し、SUB3 のビルドを実行しないかと思います。

```
all: subtask1 subtask2 subtask3

subtask1:
    make -C SUB1 

subtask2:
    make -C SUB2 

subtask3:
    make -C SUB3
```

Comment: 実際は、対象のSUM makefile が多く１個ずつ記載するのが面倒でループしていました。説明不足で申し訳ありません。

Comment: 特に謝っていただく必要はありませんが、自分が書いている処理を正しく理解してください。「forはシェルが処理している」ということを理解していれば make の問題ではなくシェルの書き方に過ぎないということがわかるかと思います。ちなみにシェルに動作させる場合その環境で使用されているシェルによって動作が変わる場合があるためそのあたりは注意してください。₍そもそもWindows環境のcmd.exeでは動かないとかも)